# RPi b+ randomly close the browser on a few

Tags: networking, web-browsers, chromium

I use RPi B+ with epiphany and chromium installed. I get very strange behavior when I browsing through both these browsers. When I open 4-5 tabs and switch between them, browsers crashes and closes. Why does I get this error?

Comment: Have you checked the memory consumption?  If you are on raspbian, try `grep "oom-killer" /var/log/syslog` and see if anything comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Broswers can really be RAM hogs. Especially Chrome. Each tab you open is more and more RAM being used. As stated already, when your OS notices you're running out of RAM it will kill processes to ensure the OS has enough RAM to do what it needs to do.

Here is a great article with more details:http://lifehacker.com/why-chrome-uses-so-much-freaking-ram-1702537477

And, I would recommend "[The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en)" extension as a potential solution to this problem. You might notice decreased performance when going back and forth between tabs, but at least it *shouldn't* crash on you.

Comment: Keep in mind, a single chrome tab will consume 20-100mb RAM for EACH tab (size depends on webpage). Pis only come with 1GB RAM (Rpi2B) and your OS is going to take a good chunk of that (even more so when your using the GUI). You *probably* have only ~80mb of free RAM on your PI for Chrome to use... Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1720&p=90528

Answer (score -1):

When Chrome uses more memory than the rpi has it can be killed, solution: use more swap, run nothing else when using chrome, use only one tab, use the official browser instead, use uadblock, use a pi2 or something with up to 16GB ram for bloated sites or tab heavy browsing.

Comment: Hard solution :D. You can offer use more powerful than PI board cob too :P

Comment: Adblock uses a ton of RAM.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Adblock uses less ram than most advertisements, but yes there are lighter solutions.